# Showing paginate links with an eloquent subquery

Tags: laravel

This is the query that I have:

```
$post = Post::with([
    'comments' => function($query) {
        $query->where('comment', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        $query->paginate(15);
    }])
->findOrFail($id);
```

How do I now show the pagination links in my blade view?

Regarding pagination, these don't work. Note that I have `comments()` as a relationship on the Post Model.

```
$post-links()
$post-comments()->links()
$post->comments-links()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->setRelation('pagenateComments', $post->comments()
                                                    ->where('comment', 'like', '%{$search}%')
                                                    ->paginate(15));
```

and use this in your blade
`$post->pagenateComments->links()`

Comment: Thanks. That should work. I ended up using: `$post = Post::findOrFail($id);` and then `$comments = $post->comments()-where('comment', 'like', "%{$search}%")->paginate(15);` and in the view `$responses->links()`